# Retirar de um aquivo uma linha e retornar editado

Tags: regex, sed

Preciso de uma ajuda tenho essa String: 'version'=>'0.51.9.beta', e preciso que retorne somente 0.51.9.beta sem aspas e sem a virgula isso com o sed,

com esse comando **sed -n -e "/version/ s/.*=>' *//p" config/params.php** retorna 0.51.9.beta',

Comment: [Você já fez esta pergunta anteriormente](/q/527898/70), duplicações não são permitidas aqui.  Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).